# What is the name of the parts that cover up the wires in front of the front wheel?

Tags: toyota, wheels, parts, bumper

I bumped into a box when I was in the highway and my bumper is damaged. After that I went to a body shop nearby and he re-attached my bumper back but then I realized the parts that cover up the wires in front of my left front wheel is gone, so now the wires in front of the left front wheel is exposed and the right front wheel is not.

He mentioned the name of it and said I will be okay without it, but if I insist in fixing it he can order the parts and install it for me. Since I was in a hurry for a meeting at work, I left without writing down the name of the thing now I have some time to google something myself, but I don't know what to google. The closest thing I found is "fender", but that's not actually it.

Can someone let me know

1. What is the name of it?
2. Is it ok to not have it?

P.S.: I have a 7 year old toyota corolla if that matters.

Comment: Can you take a picture? I think you’re talking about the inner fender liner.

Comment: @Ben I googled "inner fender liner" and it seems to be right, thanks! Is it ok if I don't have a "inner fender liner" for my left front wheel?

Comment: I think : several names several countries... as long as you are now sorted that’s fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try “splash guard” is one that comes to mind.

Edit:
As to not having one, not a good idea - things can get wet / covered in mud or snow that shouldn’t and it can change cooling air flow as well.

Comment: I googled "splash guard" and "inner fender liner" it seems that both are right, thanks! Is it ok if I don't have a "splash guard" for my left front wheel?

Comment: @user3667089 it helps keep debris and liquids from getting on stuff. I recently repaired a Chrysler 300 that was missing it’s lower engine cover and the tires wore holes in the liner. Road salt and water got into the power module and shorted the network bus causing a no start. So both are pretty important.

Answer (score 2):

Its called the.. Inner wheel arch.